Create a custom list from existing list will not preserve the list view column format, can we fix this?
I have created a custom list which contain those features:-

Custom site content type
Custom site columns
2 views
I defined 2 formats for the list view columns.

Then I created a new custom list from existing list. where I got a new list with the same components as the original list except for the list view columns format, which were not preserved. is there a way to fix this?
Thanks
